# Cannot override static roles in Elastic Security

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I have an issue about Elastic Security. I use OpenDistro for Elastic Security, it's a 3rd party tool. I solved SSL and I set up all system using Docker.

After containers are up, I have to run the given command inside of container.

./plugins/opendistro_security/tools/securityadmin.sh -cd ./plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/ -icl -nhnv -cacert ./config/root-ca.pem -cert ./config/admin.pem -key ./config/admin-key.pem

I expect certificate and key files are replaced and securityadmin script is run. However, I'm taking this error.

Open Distro Security Admin v7
Will connect to localhost:9300 ... done
Connected as *** LDAP information is here ***
Elasticsearch Version: 7.10.2
Open Distro Security Version: 1.13.1.0
Contacting elasticsearch cluster 'elasticsearch' and wait for YELLOW clusterstate ...
Clustername: docker-cluster
Clusterstate: GREEN
Number of nodes: 1
Number of data nodes: 1
.opendistro_security index does not exists, attempt to create it ... done (0-all replicas)
Populate config from /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig
Will update '_doc/config' with ./plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/config.yml
SUCC: Configuration for 'config' created or updated
Will update '_doc/roles' with ./plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/roles.yml
SUCC: Configuration for 'roles' created or updated
Will update '_doc/rolesmapping' with ./plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/roles_mapping.yml
SUCC: Configuration for 'rolesmapping' created or updated
Will update '_doc/internalusers' with ./plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/internal_users.yml
SUCC: Configuration for 'internalusers' created or updated
Will update '_doc/actiongroups' with ./plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/action_groups.yml
SUCC: Configuration for 'actiongroups' created or updated
Will update '_doc/tenants' with ./plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/tenants.yml
SUCC: Configuration for 'tenants' created or updated
Will update '_doc/nodesdn' with ./plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/nodes_dn.yml
SUCC: Configuration for 'nodesdn' created or updated
Will update '_doc/whitelist' with ./plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/whitelist.yml
SUCC: Configuration for 'whitelist' created or updated
Will update '_doc/audit' with ./plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/audit.yml
SUCC: Configuration for 'audit' created or updated
**FAIL: 1 nodes reported failures. First failure is FailedNodeException[Failed node [Hrbny7ZxSby9_eNNUodPEA]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[37c674e27698][172.23.0.2:9300][cluster:admin/opendistro_security/config/update[n]]]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[static_resource_exception: Cannot override static roles];
FAIL: Expected 1 nodes to return response, but got 0
Done with failures**

I don't know how I can solve this problem.
I'm waiting your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are trying to create roles that already defined in static_config folder. Compare the security_config/roles.yml with src/main/resources/static_config/static_roles.yml to see if there are any duplicates. In case of duplicates, rename or remove roles from security_config/roles.yml file.